# Identify auto generated TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textchanged

I want to build a simple properties view where one can change each value.

The properties are grouped by one name like this:

- **name1**: *property1,property2*
- **name2**: *property1,property2*
- ...

So I created a DataGrid with a template to fill the grid (note that I removed every style property etc. and the text values are also just examples):

```
<DataGrid Name="propertyGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property Group Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding propertyGroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property 1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding property1}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property 2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding property2}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see I'm now trying to add a `TextChanged` event and there is my problem: Where do I get the `propertyGroupName` information from, since I only  need to change the `property2` from a specific `propertyGroup`.

I'm ready for **any** hint or solution... maybe the 'auto gen datagrid' isn't the best decision here?

**Edit** My code behind. Here you can see the page filling the `DataGrid` and the class I am binding to (note that the method `GetPropertyX` is just reading my property file):

```
    public PropertiesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<PropertyGroup> properties = new List<PropertyGroup>();
        properties.Add(GetPropertyGroup("propertyGroup1"));
        properties.Add(GetPropertyGroup("propertyGroup2"));
        properties.Add(GetPropertyGroup("propertyGroup3"));

        propertyGrid.ItemsSource = properties;

    }

    private PropertyGroup GetPropertyGroup(string propertyGroupName)
    {
        return new CarrierConfig()
        {
            PropertyGroupName = propertyGroupName,
            Property1 = GetProperty1(propertyGroupName),
            Property2 = GetProperty2(propertyGroupName)
        };
    }

    public class PropertyGroup
    {
        public string PropertyGroupName { get; set; }
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for a property grid ? if so have a look [here](http://wpg.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this with a DataGrid. If you post the class you are binding to I can help you further. Maybe a TreeView with a HierarchicalDataTemplate would be a good choice

Comment: @Dominik look at my edit... maybe that will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `PropertyGroup` to the `TextBox` as `Tag`, then you can read it in the event handler and check the property group name:

```
<DataGrid Name="propertyGrid">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property Group Name">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding propertyGroupName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property 1">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding property1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property 2">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding property2}" Tag="{Binding Path=.}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The only difference is `Tag="{Binding Path=.}"`.

Event handler:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (sender as TextBox);
        if ((textbox.Tag as PropertyGroup).PropertyGroupName == "the name you want")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, but it looks a bit risky ... but since I'm new to C# and WPF I can't evaluate this solution :) ... I'll use it! Thanks ;)